# Diagnostic CANoe Automation via CANoe COM object

Tags: automation, com, canoe, automotive

I am currently automating vector Canoe tool to send CAN data to my target . I was successful able to load a configuration file and control the environment variables using the Canoe COM object. Now i am in need to automate the diagnostics responses and request via the object. I was able to find the api in the COM object help hire achy but i am not sure about the parameters to be passed. [The Snapshot of diagnostics create request API](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1q4FD.png)

Here i could not understand what is the primitive path in the argument? Please provide explanation for the same. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The parameter to be passed is the same you would use with a `on diagRequest` handler, e.g.:

```
on diagRequest FaultMemory_ReadAllIdentified
```

The easiest way to get to this parameter is by browsing to the request in the CAPL browser.